# Displaying directory listings using regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, java-io

Here's a code snippet from 'Thinking in Java':

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class DirList {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File path = new File(".");
        String[] list;
        if(args.length == 0){
            list = path.list();
        }
        else{
            //System.out.println(args[0]);
            list = path.list(new DirFilter(args[0]));

        }

        Arrays.sort(list, new AlphabeticComparator());
        System.out.println(list.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.println(list[i]);
        }
    }
}

class DirFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private Pattern pattern;
    public DirFilter(String regex){
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        //System.out.println(pattern);

    }
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
     // Strip path information, search for regex:
        return pattern.matcher(new File(name).getName()).matches();

    }
} ///:~
```

It should ideally list out all the .java files in the current directory, but it does not. From what I could observe, the array 'list' does not contain any elements at all if I pass C.*.java as a command line argument.
I haven't included the AlphabeticComaparator class here; all it does is sort the files in alphabetical order.

I am new to both File I/O and Regular Expressions; would really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: If you want to list all java files, your pattern should be `.*java`

Comment: Or .*\\.java to force it to detect the dot and avoid false positives like blahblahjava with no extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line, either of these will work for listing all .java files:

```
java DirList .*\\.java
java DirList '.*\.java'
```

If you don't have any java filenames that start with C, you'll come up empty with the C.*.java.